# Using `std::array` size in another `std::array`

Tags: c++11, c++17

I have an `std::array` defined in one part of the code

```
std::array<int, 303> data;
```

I would like to declare another `std::array` with the same size. Like this:

```
std::array<double, data.size()> other_data;
```

Basically, I would like to use the information from `data` as opposed to using the same constant.
But it fails to compile with `-std=c++11`. 
Is it even possible and if yes, what is the best way to do this?

Comment: That should work with `C++11`. What error message do you get?

Comment: `error: call to non-constexpr function ‘std::array<_Tp, _Nm>::size_type std::array<_Tp, _Nm>::size() const [with _Tp = row; long unsigned int _Nm = 303; std::array<_Tp, _Nm>::size_type = long unsigned int]’ ` as if the `size()` is not `const`. Will it only work if `data` is a `const`?

Comment: Ok, I found _my_ problem: in my code, the `data` is declared as `extern` in a header file. However, the declaration of `other_data` only works if `data` is a `const`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is ok and compiles without a problem: https://godbolt.org/z/pjFmbD. No, `data` doesn't need to be const, because `std::array::size` is `const constexpr`: 
 https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array/size

Answer (score -3):

You can compute the element count from sizeof

```
sizeof(data)/sizeof(data[0])
```

Comment: that is unsafe, error prone and an anti pattern in modern C++.